Running different laser diodes using a single DC Source
I am trying to run two laser diodes (650 nm and 1550 nm). I made two current regulators to limit the diode current using the circuit given here.
I connected these current regulators to a variable DC power supply. However, I notice that as I try to increase the current in one laser diode (D1) through its regulator, the voltage of the other diode (D2) drops resulting in the diode turning off. Is there a way to isolate both of these current regulators while using a single power supply?

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Your schematic indicates that you’re connecting two 8V linear regulators to an 8V power supply. Is that correct or are you using a higher voltage supply than indicated?

Since I am not using the IC to regulate the voltage, rather to regulate the current. Does it actually matter? I am also seeing a drop in voltage of around 0.3-0.5v due to the IC.

Regulator output characteristics are not defined when Vin is less than Vout+Vdropout. Can you bump your supply to 10V or use a lower voltage VR chip?

Okay, Can I use IC 7505 in the same configuration instead?

Assuming you meant 7805, and yes.

I meant TL750M05C..

Your schematic specified a generic 7808, which is a standard linear regulator. You then pointed us to a specific vendor (ST) for an application circuit using their specific linear regulator. Now you are specifying a TL-series LDO from TI. In the future, please be specific about part numbers, because it can make a big difference when analyzing a circuit, especially for nonstandard uses.

The ADJ pin and associated capacitors and pot must be connected to the minus of the power supply.  It won't work floating as you show.  And they are connected as voltage regulators, not current regulators.  If you want a constant current then use an LM317 in a constant current circuit.

@CarlRutschow This schematic is a typical adjustable current source using a linear regulator. When using linear regulators in this way, they do not need a connection to ground. You see them typically more often with the wiper and the bottom of the potentiometer connected, though the current flowing here isn't that significant

The current regulator has a voltage drop of the regulator voltage, PLUS the required headroom (ideally 3V, but 1.5V or so will do at low currents), PLUS the voltage drop across the laser diode. Looks like 650nm laser diodes can have Vf of the order of 2.8V, while the 1550nm is considerably lower.
Taking 3V + 8V + 2.8V you would need almost 14V in to get the regulators to work properly, or 11V with a 7805. Your circuit is actually worse than this analysis would indicate- see below.
The regulator uses a few mA internally, so the minimum current will be around 3.5mA typically, no matter how high the resistor goes.
As noted elsewhere, if you crank the pot all the way to one end you'll damage the laser diode and/or the pot since the current will exceed 1A, so add a resistor to the 'top' of the pot to prevent that.
P.S. if you insist on using this kind of current regulator, it would be better to use the circuit shown in the datasheet you linked- ie. connect the pot as a rheostat. Here is a comparison of the correct circuit (left) and your circuit (right), both with 7805 regulators, both with 12V in, and varying the LED voltage from 0 to 5V.

As you can see, the datasheet circuit (green trace) has superior compliance voltage.

Any voltage regulator, even an LDO, has a nonzero dropout voltage. You are trying to supply your 8V LDO with precisely 8V, which falls outside of the chip’s designed operating range and usually leads to undefined behavior, such as that which you are seeing.
The solution is to either increase Vin above Vout + Vdropout or to choose a regulator with a lower regulation voltage.
Since you are trying to use this LDO as a constant current source, I should point out two things:

Most VRs have a minimum load current requirement that must be met
for proper operation. (For example, the ST chip which you linked in
your original question explicitly states that a minimum load of
5mA must be provided.) The datasheet for your proposed chip
(TI TL750M05C), doesn’t explicitly mention this, but the electrical
characteristics are only provided down to Io=5mA. Given that your
original schematic was trying to source 6mA at its low end ((8Vin - 2Vdropout) / 1kΩ), this seems too close to the margin limits. You should add another current sink in parallel with the load to always consume at least 5mA.
When you set R1 or R2 too close to 0Ω, you are going to exceed the maximum allowable current in either your diode or your regulator. An additional fixed resistor in series with each pot is an easy current limiting solution.


The other answers are good and explain your headroom problem. But here is how you would normally do this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
R1 (I_lim) is chosen for the maximum current acceptable:
R1 = XX/I_max, where XX is the regulator voltage, 1.25 for adj. versions.
Pot R2 is chosen to set to adjust the minimum current:
I_min = XX/(R1+R2)
You can sweep between I_max and I_min. There is no "off".
Power supply (PS1) voltage has to be greater than all voltage drops at worst-case:
PS1 > Vd_D1 + XX + dropout voltage of reg (2V in your case).
Upper limit of PS1 is going to be governed either by max absolute voltage rating - Vd_D1. Or, thermal management:
P(heat) = I_max * XX
Both lasers will maintain independent constant-current behavior if these operating conditions are maintained.
